# Retrieve Values from Db by passing parameter from previous Page - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am new to ASP.Net,

I am having an issue retrieving Employee information from DB when passing the UserID from a previous page. 
i have managed to pass the userID when selected from the Data Grid in Page 1 but when loading page 2 it gives me an error: invalid column name 'Value of string passed'

below is my code:

**Page 1**:

protected void imgBtnView_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

```
{
        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)sender;
        string UserID = imgBtn.CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("Employee.aspx?UserID=" + UserID);
}
```

**Page 2** :

**Page Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
   txtEmployeeNo.Text = Request.QueryString["UserID"]; 
   FillFields(txtEmployeeNo.Text);
}
```

**Method FillFields**

```
private void FillFields(string User_ID)
{
    String commandString = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Tbl_Employee] WHERE 
    [UserID] = "+ User_ID;
    DataRow dr = Global.StartQuery(commandString).Rows[0]; -- > global class
    txtEmployeeNo.Text = User_ID;
    txtFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString(); 
    txtLastName.Text =  dr["LastName"].ToString();
}
```

Please tell me what's wrong in the code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you see your user id in query string. Passing user id in query string is bad idea use session instead. If you are getting user id then in commandString convert User_ID to String either by Conver.ToString() metho or User_ID.ToString()

Comment: can you advise more more on the session method ?

Comment: `Response.Redirect("Employee.aspx?UserID=" + UserID);`
better:
`Response.Redirect("Employee.aspx?UserID=" + Server.UrlEncode(UserID));`

Comment: `private void FillFields(string User_ID)`
better:
`private void FillFields(string userId)`

Comment: `txtFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();`
exception for nullable field.
Check if dr["foo"] is null

Answer (score 2):

User the following line of code.

```
String commandString = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Tbl_Employee] WHERE 
[UserID] = '"+User_ID+"'";
```

Comment: i couldnt as my reputation should be above 15. but your solution have worked

Comment: Use Parameters! Don't concatenate strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this code to Page_Load event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   //Your operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing sensitive information in browser url is highly discourage. If required information should be hashed or encrypted (encryption is recommended). Instead of passing values in query string session can be used. Though still session can be hijacked; session can be considered more secure than plain text in url. So using session your above problem can be solved as

```
protected void imgBtnView_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)sender;
   //string UserID = imgBtn.CommandArgument; //just ignored intermediate value holder
   Session["UserID"] = imgBtn.CommandArgument;
   Response.Redirect("Employee.aspx");
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
  if(!IsPostBack) //Do stuff only during page first load.
  {
   //Check if session is null. 
   string userId = Session["UserID"]==null? String.Empty : Session["UserID"].ToString(); 
   txtEmployeeNo.Text = userId;
   if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
   {
      FillFields(userId);
   }
  }
}

//This method should return datatable or DataRow and avoid setting control value. 
//Returing datatable or DataRow makes this method more reusable.
private void FillFields(string User_ID)
{
    //This way of execuring sql query is highly discourage. 
    //You should use parametrized sql command or use store procedure.
    String commandString = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Tbl_Employee] WHERE 
    [UserID] = '"+ User_ID + "'"; 
    DataRow dr = Global.StartQuery(commandString).Rows[0]; -- > global class
    txtEmployeeNo.Text = User_ID;
    txtFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString(); 
    txtLastName.Text =  dr["LastName"].ToString();
}
```

So few changes in Page_Load and method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
      if(!IsPostBack) //Do stuff only during page first load.
      {
       //Check if session is null. 
       string userId = Session["UserID"]==null? String.Empty : Session["UserID"].ToString(); 
       txtEmployeeNo.Text = userId;
       if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
       {
          DataRow dr = FillFields(userId);
          txtEmployeeNo.Text = User_ID;
          txtFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString(); 
          txtLastName.Text =  dr["LastName"].ToString();
       }
      }
    }

private DataRow FillFields(string User_ID)
    {
        //This way of execuring sql query is highly discourage. 
        //You should use parametrized sql command or use store procedure.
        String commandString = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Tbl_Employee] WHERE 
        [UserID] = '"+ User_ID + "'"; 
        DataRow dr = Global.StartQuery(commandString).Rows[0]; -- > global class
        return dr;
    }
```

Still FillFields can through exception when invalid UserID is passed. Say UserId value is 5 and there is no record for that user ID then FillFields will not return datarow thus

```
DataRow dr = Global.StartQuery(commandString).Rows[0];
//will throw exception as you are trying to access first row 
//where row are not available. You must handle this scenario.
```